# Words that result from a gradual distortion of other words

Tags: vocabulary

Among others, I've heard the following words and their supposed origins:

- Beef: Comes from the french word "boeuf".
- Marmelade: Contraction of "Mary" and "malade" according to some story about a doctor using a mixture including oranges to treat Mary Queen of Scots.
- Mayday: Could come from the french expression "M'aider".

Is there a technical term to describe words like this that come from the gradual distortion of other words (either more ancient or of foreign origin)?

Comment: Every word is a gradual distortion of other words, either more ancient or of foreign origin. *Father* is a distortion of "fæder", *between* is a distortion of "betweonum", meaning "by two each", and *a* and *one* are both distortions of "an".

Comment: @RedDwight You're right. That's how languages evolve. I'll rephrase. Is there a word that describes this process?

Comment: You mean besides _evolution_?

Comment: Other than "(language) evolution"? Don't think so. Each word has its very own history. [Vowel shifts](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/238/300), [malapropisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malapropism), [eggcorns](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/835/300), [metaanalysis](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/33155/a-whole-nother-way-of-looking-at-things), [metathesis](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/10242/300)... There are way too many way too different processes at work. Trying to find a hypernym for them all will only get you something as vapid as "change" or, well, "evolution".

Comment: I understand and thank you for the links. Looks like I have a bit of reading to do :)

Comment: "Marmelade" is nothing to do with Mary, despite the popular bit of etymythology you quote: it's actually from Portuguese "marmelo" = "quince".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term sometimes used is *corruption*.

Answer (score 1):

There are many factors and processes at work here, just one of which is [*anglicisation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglicisation):

> **Anglicisation** or **anglicization** is the process of converting oral or written elements of any other
>   language into a form that is more
>   comprehensible to an English speaker; or in general, of altering something so
>   that it becomes English in form or character. It is also called anglification, anglifying, or Englishing. The term most often refers to the
>   process of altering the pronunciation or
>   spelling of a foreign word when it is
>   borrowed into English. Personal names
>   may also be anglicised. This was rather
>   common for names of antiquity or of foreign heads of state, and it has also
>   been common among immigrants to English-speaking countries (for
>   example, Battenberg became Mountbatten).